# why hashMap multithreading make a specific Thread to starve

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have this scenrio:

```
private static final Map<String, Boolean> availables = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

**1 single Thread keep  getting an available task and distribute it among worker (let's call it distributor)**

```
public static String getAnAvailable() {

    synchronized (availables){

        for(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : availables.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue() == true){
                entry.setValue(false);
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

**1 single Thread run this code (let's call it Updater):**

```
while(true){
  ...
  synchronized (availables) {
      for(String deleteIt : delete){
          if(available.containsKey(deleteIt)){
              available.remove(deleteIt);
          }
      }
      for(String name : names){
          if(!available.containsKey(name)){
              available.put(name, true);
          }
      }
  }
  ...
}
```

I tried to use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of manual `synchronization` but it can `throw Exception` in `getAnAvailable` method, the reason is obvious, because if updater thread changes the size of the map then within getAnAvailable we get iteration exception. so no point of using that.

now my problem is that for some reason `Updater` starves indefinitely on exactly the third run... 
basically it gets stock when it tries to acquire the `luck`.

for the life of me I have no idea why that happens. can anyone see something that I don't see here?

Comment: Well this is not an answer, but did you realized that your map is declared final? This is wrong, you want to modify the map with updater process, so you are better not to use the map as final. Have you tried?

Comment: @malaguna well I only declared it once,updater only add and remove entry. it doesn't change the reference to the object

Comment: Sorry, I messed myself with unmodifiable map. You are right.

Comment: Maybe the while(true) { synchronized(..) { ... }} is hoarding the lock. You could try adding a Thread.sleep or Thread.yield inside that loop to see if that mitigates the problem.

Comment: @emilianogc what do you mean? well I put three dots, meaning I omitted the useless information. so before and after `synchronized block`there are loads of codes

Comment: Just my 2 cents. This can also due to HashMap re-sizing. Can you give us some details like how many element can be there in map at max.

Comment: @DhruvG size may vary really, but in practice it should be no more than 500k

Comment: If its possible try initializing array with*desired size Nd test it.

Comment: @DhruvG well, to be honest. This problem annoyed me so much that I completely changed my design. now instead of having one single service, I'm running two and split the work ( new code is very messy but it atleast work)